# Is it possible to put multiple transitions into a single frame?

Tags: beamer, transition

For instance, I have the code

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\transdissolve
\frametitle{Resultados Básicos}
No capítulo 1 destacamos os seguintes resultados básicos da Teoria de Grupos que serão importantes ao longo do texto:

\pause
\begin{itemize}%[<+-|alert@+>]
\item O Teorema de Lagrange.

\pause
\item Homomorfismo e Isomorfismo.

\pause
\item Subgrupos Normais e estrutura dos Grupos Quocientes.

\pause
\item O Princípio da Contagem.
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I wanted to put different transitions for each of the items and keep the first frame transition. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass overlay instructions to the `\trans...<>` commands:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\transdissolve<1>
\transblindshorizontal<2>
\frametitle{Resultados Básicos}
No capítulo 1 destacamos os seguintes resultados básicos da Teoria de Grupos que serão importantes ao longo do texto:

\pause
\begin{itemize}%[<+-|alert@+>]
\item O Teorema de Lagrange.

\pause
\item Homomorfismo e Isomorfismo.

\pause
\item Subgrupos Normais e estrutura dos Grupos Quocientes.

\pause
\item O Princípio da Contagem.
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I got it! Thank you! How do I choose the duration of the transition?

Comment: @Greg For example with `\transdissolve<1>[duration=2]` for a duration of 2 seconds